# Update multiple columns in an IFF statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I check the below code I am getting an

> incorrect syntax

error near IFF statement in Management Studio.

It has been a while since I wrote SQL but if I remember correctly this should work

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
UPDATE dbo.EPC_Parcel_Data
IFF
   ( Acreage > 0   
     ( SET [Lot - TSF]                             = (ACREAGE * 43500),
           [Lot - Total Square Feet]               = (ACREAGE * 43500),
               [Lot - UnImproved Square Feet]          = ([Lot - Total Square Feet] - IMPSQFT),
           [Total Bid at $0#22 Per Square Foot]    = ([Lot - UnImproved Square Feet] * .22)  
     ),
     (
       SET [Lot - TSF]                             = 0,
           [Lot - Total Square Feet]               = 0,
           [Lot - UnImproved Square Feet]          = 0,
           [Total Bid at 22 Cents Per Square Foot] = 0
     )
   )
WHERE Acreage = 0;
```

If the acreage was greater than zero, it would compute the 4 data fields else it would set them to zero.

Comment: Did you check the documentation?

Comment: Contradiction, `Acreage > 0`, but you've already `WHERE Acreage = 0`. What are you trying to do? A [mcve] would make this much clearer.

Comment: Also, note that tables have _columns_, not fields.

Comment: Do you mean `IIF` as opposed to `IFF`? Cos IIF is an expression not a statement and as such can only return a scaler value, not execute a conditional statement - as the documentation makes clear.

Comment: And you can't conditionally choose which columns you update. It has to be static. It really has been a long time or else you used a different RDBMS in the past

Answer (score 1):

No, this can't work on SQL Server. It doesn't even make sense because you have a where clause that limits the update only to records where Acreage = 0, so what's the point of checking in the set clause the value of Acreage? it's 0, can't be anything else.

Also, SQL Server doesn't have an `IFF` statement, it has an `IIF` expression which is basically syntactic sugar for a simple `case then else` expression - meaning you can't use it like you've written.

An educated guess to what you're attempting to write would be something like this:

```
UPDATE dbo.EPC_Parcel_Data
SET [Lot - TSF]                          = (ACREAGE * 43500), 
    [Lot - Total Square Feet]            = (ACREAGE * 43500),
    [Lot - UnImproved Square Feet]       = IIF(ACREAGE > 0, ([Lot - Total Square Feet] - IMPSQFT), 0),
    [Total Bid at $0#22 Per Square Foot] = IIF(ACREAGE > 0, ([Lot - UnImproved Square Feet] * .22), 0)
```